# Recurring Contributions count not match: "Find Contributions" vs API4 Contribution::get

Tags: recurring-contributions, apiv4

Api call below returns **1078** contributions

```
$contributions = civicrm_api4('Contribution', 'get', [
  'select' => [
'row_count',
    ],
 'where' => [
['contribution_recur_id', 'IS NOT NULL'], 
['is_test', '=', FALSE],
['contribution_recur_id.start_date', '>=', '2016-01-01'],
   ],
  'checkPermissions' => FALSE,
  ]);
```

...while Find Contributions search below

```
Is a Template Contribution = '0' ...AND...
Recurring Contribution Start Date - greater than or equal to "January 1st, 2016 12:00 am" ...AND...
Contribution Status In Completed ...AND...
All recurring contributions regardless of payments
```

returns only **629** records.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you also add same filters in api4 as Find Contribution

1. is_template = 0
2. contribution_status_id = Completed

Comment: right, contribution status is the key, thanks!